# How to make user aware of the secondary (right) navigation drawer?

Tags: android, material-design, sidebar

I have a second navigation drawer on the right. But I have no special indication for it so the user doesn't get to be aware of its existence. I don't want to open it every time the user opens the related page. So which approach should I take?

Should I use an icon on the app bar or either show a tiny portion of it on page open?

I've been searching all over the material guides but I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: could you provide ur current design so we can have more insight?

Comment: it's actually nothing special. a free page with a main navigation drawer (with a hamburger icon in the app bar). And a second navigation drawer which you will never get to know its existence unless you accidentally slide it from the edge.

Comment: Could you give us some additional information about what is in the primary and secondary navigation? In general, though, I think you will want to give users an icon that will logically relate to the list they're getting in that drawer…not another generic menu icon. Or, maybe it is possible to merge the two navigation lists (with a tree or something like that), so that users only need to learn about one of the lists. Without more information about your app (content and subject matter would be more helpful than screens) it is hard to be less vague than that. :)

Comment: why have a secondary nav if you don't want people to be aware of it?

Comment: @tina Could you share a wireframe of your design looks. That will help visualize and get better solutions from the fellow designers.

Answer (score 2):

You can get user to  used to it. Just put the (icon or name of the action) what it is intended for . It should be on the App bar on the extreme right position. So whenever user tap on icon, it will just slide near from it (from right side).So from next time user can just slide it.